# Multi-Project Template creates only empty folder

Tags: project-template, multi-project

I have created a multi-project template. But I'm not able to get it working. It creates only empty folders for solution. Could not find useful info on google. Here is the template zip
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39085241/TestProjectTemplate.zip

It would be great if anyone working with templates could have a look at it and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. You just need to change the ProjectType attribute of main .vstemplate file to ProjectGroup.

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
```

Comment: I spent some 2 hours trying to fix this issue, this simple solution just saved my day. Thanks!